# Laravel Jquery: URLs are being read as &quot;

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm making an app with Laravel. I have a variable called dataActivity, and I want to use this as an image url. Since Laravel uses `{{ URL::asset('path') }}` to make a link, I did this:

```
$('.box').css("background-image", "url('{{ URL::asset('icons/"+dataActivity+".png')}}')");
```

However, the not found error outputs the link as `http://localhost:8000/pictures/&quot;+dataActivity+&quot;.png`

As you can see, there are `&quot`s where there shouldn't be. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$('.box').css("background-image", "url('{!! URL::asset('icons/"+dataActivity+".png')!!}')");
```

instead of

```
$('.box').css("background-image", "url('{{ URL::asset('icons/"+dataActivity+".png')}}')");
```